# jQuery - remove table row <tr> by clicking a <td>

Tags: jquery

I am making a table in which you can add aditional rows. When you add a row you can either save it or cancel it, by clicking cancel the row will be removed. It works with one row but when I create like six of them and click cancel the selected row wont be removed but the last row will. Here my Code so far. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<head>
  <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".edit").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("edit "+id);
  });
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("delete "+id);
  });
  $("#newbutton").click(function() {
  var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    $("tr:last").after("<tr id="+randomnumber+"><td><form><input style='width: 80%'></form></td><td class=ok>OK</td><td id="+randomnumber+" class=cancel>Cancel</td></tr>").ready(function() {
      $("tr td .cancel").click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
      $(".ok").click(function() {
        alert("OK!");
      });
    });
  })
}); 
  </script>
</head>
<table border=1 id=table>
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>Bombai</td><td id=1 class=edit>edit</td><td id=1 class=delete>delete</td></tr> 
<tr><td>London</td><td id=2 class=edit>edit</td><td id=2 class=delete>delete</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Rom</td><td id=3 class=edit>edit</td><td id=3 class=delete>delete</td></tr> 
</table><label id=newbutton>New Place</label>
```

Comment: Sorry but none of both answers have until now solved my question :(

Comment: SORRY WAS TOTALY WRONG MY PROBLEM JUST GOT SOLVED WITH duckyflip's ANSWER!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are dynamically adding rows to the DOM I'd suggest you use the **[live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)** function:

```
$("tr td .cancel").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent("tr:first").remove()
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much duckyflip, you helped me alot!

Comment: The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the on() method instead. Citated from: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_live.asp

Comment: this is the latest one...
      $( document ).on( "click", ".remove", function(){  $(this).parent("tr:first").remove() });

Answer (score 12):

```
<td><a class="delete" onclick ="delete_user($(this))">Delete</a></td>
```

in javascript

```
    function delete_user(row)
    {
        row.closest('tr').remove();


    }
```

Answer (score 7):

you can try do something like this,

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXB4Z/)</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<table border=2>
    <tr>
        <td>jQuery</td>
        <td>mootools</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dojo</td>
        <td>FUEL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Raphael</td>
        <td>Rico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SproutCore</td>
        <td>Lively Kernel</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### jQuery :

```
$(function() {
   $('tr')
       .find('td')
       .append('<input type="button" value="Delete" class="del"/>')
       .parent()//traversing to 'tr' Element
       .append('<td><input type="button" value="Delete row" class="delrow" /></td>');

    $('.del').click(function() {
       $(this).parent().remove(); //Deleting TD element
    });

    $('.delrow').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Deleting the Row (tr) Element
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not scoping your removal operation to the context of the row you're adding.  Try:

```
$(this).find("tr td .cancel").click(...)
```

Will need to do the same deal with the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

**script**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
        $("#Add").click(function () {
            $("#tbl1").append(markup);

        });
        $("#remove").click(function () {
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

**body**

Add Row

```
<table border="5px" cellspacing="3px" cellpadding="10px" id="tbl1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>
            Select
        </td>
        <td>
            column 2
        </td>
        <td>
            column 3
        </td>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button id="remove">Delete Row</button>
```