# How can I remove a table row base from a td using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tablerow

For example I have this table:

```
id  name action
1   john x
2   doe  x
```

If I click x in the row when id is 1 it will be remove, how can I do that?

```
$('.btnDeleteitem').live('click', function() {
            //
            $.ajax({
                url: 'wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/Delete.Item.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: { asin: $(this).attr('alt') },
                success:function(){
                    //
                }
            });
```

Note: data from table is from database

Comment: do you want to remove it from visual or from DB also ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the data from the database, or just what's displayed in the HTML page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926319/jquery-remove-table-row-tr-by-clicking-a-td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/s9cwt/

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>X</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:contains('X')").click(function(){
      $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    });
});​
```

if you want to delete only the rows that has id=1 you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:contains('X')").click(function(){
      if($(this).parent('tr').find('td').first().text()==1)
        $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    });
});​
```

Comment: What if the name is "Xavier"? Then just clicking on the name would delete it. I know the OP didn't show any HTML, but it's reasonably clear from the JS shown that the "X" is some kind of button or img element with the `'.btnDeleteitem'` class - the problem is how to delete the row, not how to create the event handler...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you clicked on `x` of any row, this should work:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove()
```

there are certainly faster ways which you may try figure it out :). If `x` will always under `td`, you can use `parent` rather than `parents` too.

Now, if you want to remove it from database too (as someone asked in the comment), you can trigger an ajax call. However, you will also need to fetch the ID of the row. For simplicity, you can modify your table design something like:

```
<tr>
  <td class="recordID">1</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="recordID">1</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>X</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
recordID = $(this).siblings('.recordID').text();
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
$.post("/deleteRecored?id=" + recordID, function(response){ 
  //handle your response here
})
```

Comment: Why would you use `.parents()` and not `.closest()`?

Comment: surely that can be used too. i've updated it as probably it will be faster

Comment: Yep. I should've said this up front, but if the table shown is nested inside another table then `.parents()` won't work. (Or, rather, it will work too well...) This isn't a problem with `.closest()`.

Comment: how? `closest()` will also find the first matched element up the DOM tree! isn't it? it should is supposed to fail there too.

Comment: `.closest("tr")` will find the first tr up the tree, so only that tr will be removed. `.parents("tr")` will find _all_ tr elements up the tree, so then all of them would be removed. Of course this is only a problem if the table is nested inside another table...