# delete <td> that add dynamically through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a project and I already took help in it from **stackoverflow** but i am stuck once again. The problem is that a user can select number of rows he want to add but if lets us suppose he want to add three but mistakenly he enter four and add four rows and now he want to remove any single row so he could do that below is the code for it

```
$(function() {
    var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({ min: 0 });

    $( "#ok" ).click(function() {
        var spiner_val = spinner.spinner( "value" ) ;
        var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="name" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name" />&nbsp;<select><option value="">abc</option><option value="">abc</option><option value="">abc</option><option value="">abc</option></select><a href=""><img class="img-icons" src="images/delete.jpg" /></a></td></tr>';

        for(i = 0; i < spiner_val;i++){
            $(html).insertAfter('tr:last');
        }
    });
});
```

So when user click the image infront of any row that row should be deleted.thanks in advance.

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/aLZhw/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - remove table row <tr> by clicking a <td>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926319/jquery-remove-table-row-tr-by-clicking-a-td)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a class `delete` to the `a` element like `<a href="" class="delete"><img class="img-icons" src="images/delete.jpg" /></a>`

then

```
 $('#my-table').on('click', '.delete', function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     return false;
 })
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WKp73/)

Comment: also the table structure is wrong I guess you noticed, http://jsfiddle.net/aLZhw/4/

Comment: yes i got it now thanks for every thng stackoverflow always rock